# iOS UICollectionView header & footer location

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, flowlayout

Working in `iOS 7`, how does one specify where the header & footer boxes go in a `UICollectionView`?

I have a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.  I have overwritten

```
-(void)prepareLayout

-(NSArray*) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect

-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*) layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind: (NSString*)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

My problem is, I'm not sure how to specify header location.  I have already specified that a header exists in `prepareLayout`:

```
-(void)prepareLayout
{
[super prepareLayout];

boundsSize = self.collectionView.bounds.size;
midX = boundsSize.width / 2.0f;
curIndex = 0;

self.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(CELL_SIZE, TITLE_HEIGHT);
self.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TOP_INSET, LEFT_INSET, BOTTOM_INSET, RIGHT_INSET);
self.minimumLineSpacing = LINE_SPACING;
self.minimumInteritemSpacing = INTERIM_SPACING;
self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);

}
```

I just don't know the right property of my custom `FlowLayout` to set, as there doesn't seem to be something like "HeaderLocation" to set, either as a LayoutAttributes or in the layout object itself.  Right now, it is appearing to the side/between my images, when I'd like them to be appearing above each image (horizontal scroll).

I have tried the following:

```
-(UICollectionReusableView*) collectionView: (UICollectionView*)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString*)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"**ViewForSupplementaryElementOfKind called***");

    CGFloat centerX = collectionView.center.x;
    CGFloat centerY = collectionView.center.y;
    CGFloat titleWidth = [MyLayout titleWidth];
    CGFloat titleHeight = [MyLayout titleHeight];

    MyTitleView* titleView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:ImageTitleIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    titleView.frame = CGRectMake(centerX - titleWidth/2.0,
                                 0.0,
                                 titleWidth,
                                 titleHeight);

    return titleView;
}
```

This doesn't work.  The title appears above overlapped with a bunch of other titles, then the moment I start scrolling (horizontally), they jump back into the wrong place, horizontally between the images rather than above.

PS> Please do not suggest anything that has to do with NIB or XIB placement.  I am using a UICollectionView, NOT a UICollectionViewController, so I actually have no prototypical cell to work with.  The layout is being done entirely programatically -- from code alone -- so I can't simply open a XIB file and adjust the location of a text box.

Answer (score 0):

Amending the attributes returned by `-layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` is the right approach, but if you want to alter the position of offscreen headers and footers, you may need to fetch the supplementary view attributes yourself.

For example, in your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableArray *attributesArray = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy];

    // the call to super only returns attributes for headers that are in the bounds,
    // so locate attributes for out of bounds headers and include them in the array
    NSMutableIndexSet *omittedSections = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in attributesArray) {
        if (attributes.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategoryCell) {
            [omittedSections addIndex:attributes.indexPath.section];
        }
    }
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in attributesArray) {
        if ([attributes.representedElementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
            [omittedSections removeIndex:attributes.indexPath.section];
        }
    }
    [omittedSections enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:idx];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                                                            atIndexPath:indexPath];
        [attributesArray addObject:attributes];
    }];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in attributesArray) {
        if ([attributes.representedElementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {

            // adjust any aspect of each header's attributes here, including frame or zIndex

        }
    }

    return attributesArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting so much code, but could you please specify what the attribute you are editing is?  That's the most important part.  You wrote, '//adjust any aspect of each header's attributes here, including frame or zIndex' but does editing the frame there change where the header is placed? Does it just overlap whatever content is already there?  What is the specific attribute?  (There's a lot, and I don't see one in the documentation named like 'headerLocation' or 'headerOrigin' or 'headerFrame' or something like that)

Comment: "... does editing the frame there change where the header is placed? Does it just overlap whatever content is already there?" But that's exactly what the UICollectionViewLayoutAttribute's frame and zIndex properties do. Can I gently suggest you first have a read of [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: You might also find [this article](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html) helpful in gaining a deeper understanding of UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes and how they work.

Comment: Thanks, followben. Of course I already read the docs; they say "For example, header and footer views are laid out differently than cells and can be provided for individual sections or for the collection view as a whole." but they never say how to change "where" those header & footers are located.  I have same question as before: What's the name of the property that governs their location? Until that's answered, nothing else matters.

Comment: That's not how collection views work. You don't set the position of the header or footer directly; rather you set the center or frame properties on the relevant UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance returned by the layout. zIndex determines if it floats above or behind the rest of your content.

Answer (score -2):

CollectionView Header height is set below Collectionview delegate

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And Set view in Collectionview Header in Below Delegate

```
- (UICollectionReusableView*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView * view = nil;

    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader])
    {
        ColorSectionHeaderView *header = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                                            withReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ColorSectionHeaderView class])
                                                                                   forIndexPath:indexPath];
        header.sectionIndex = indexPath.section;
        header.hideDelete = collectionView.numberOfSections == 1; // hide when only one section
        header.delegate = self;
        view = header;
    }

return view;
```

}

Ragistred Class in ViewDidLoad

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{

[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([ColorSectionFooterView class]) bundle:nil]
     forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter
            withReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ColorSectionFooterView class])];

   [Super ViewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to change the height, I want to know where to change the LOCATION.  As in, I want to tell the program to put my header view ABOVE the content, at y-coordinate = 0.  Where in your solution are you explicitly telling the header to be placed at a certain location?  dequeueReusableSupplementaryView doesn't give me control over that.

Comment: What is "MyTitleView"? Is a Class?

Comment: Yes, it is my header class.

Comment: You ragitsred The class in viewDidLoad As above I edit'

Comment: Kirit Modi, I appreciate your answer but like I said, you didn't answer how to change location.